# Refresh + Clean in Eclipse, Equivalent in Intellij?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, ide

So often in Eclipse, it wouldn't recognize new files, or certain things, and have a lot of errors in the IDE. The way I always fixed with was a simple (f5) refresh on the project to have the IDE recognize all the changes and things, + a clean to rebuild after. One instance in which I had this problem was when I would run mvn clean install from the command line, and then Eclipse would get angry that I did that, since it doesn't recognize things that just appeared. The above would fix it and synch the IDE with the project, also rebuilding too.

I am wondering what is the equivalent for Intellij? Suppose I'm getting issues due to Intellij not recognizing something new, or it has something old that is cached and is using it instead of something I implemented. What is a way to get Intellij to take a step back, and look at all the files and dependencies present, to get in synch with the project that is currently there and recognize everything. So far my limited use of Intellij has not demanded that this is a possibility, but assuming I ever get in a situation where Intellij needs to re-recognize things in my project, what would I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **mvn clean install** from the command line is a different thing from IntelliJ clean install. IntelliJ used its own indexing and classpath for every project. you can see the projcet class path changes here

**File > Project Structure > Module**

[image]

And to clean the project with maven you can use the maven lifecycle window and right-hand sidebar of Intellij(if you can't see it then see it **View -> Tool Windows -> Maven**)
[image]

Comment: Ah I see. If my project uses maven, I should be using that maven life cycle to do my clean and install then.

Comment: It's the same as running mvn clean install from command line. If you want Idea to see changes from you pom files, you should press Refresh button. The one on the top left of maven window

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete refresh, then you should press File -> Invalidate Caches . Then check boxes and then press Invalidate and Restart. It's going to refresh all your projects though.

Comment: You can find a video on this complete refresh here: https://youtu.be/ctyoO6bZgjo